# Find (Ctrl+F) dialog window in PowerShell ISE in Windows 11

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

In PowerShell ISE in Windows 11 (clean install), the Find dialog box no longer searches by pressing the Enter key. It appears the "Find Next" button is no longer set as the default button for the form. Therefore, I have to either Tab five or six times to activate it or press Alt+F which is a bit awkward.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Use a different editor

Comment: ISE is practically dead. Recommended modern editor is VSCode with its PowerShell extension.

Comment: Note that he PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: That's certainly annoying, but, for the reasons stated above, it is unlikely to get fixed. Switching to a different IDE is always painful, but in the case at hand unavoidable in the long run.

Comment: I use VS Code most of the time. It doesn't have virtual space (vertical selection), so I have to supplement it with ISE sometimes. Regardless, my workflow is not the question. What happened between my Win10 and Win11 installs that made ISE this way. Is it just my machine?

Comment: I have just reproduced the issue in a Win 11 VM (build 22000.856), EN. Indeed the "Find Next" button is no longer the default.

Comment: Actually, VSCode does have vertical selection. Simply press `Shift+Alt` and use the mouse to modify selection area. If that is what you are referring to.

Comment: VS Code does have an awkward form of vertical select, but there are some operations it simply can't do without having virtual space. There are gifs that illustrate some of the differences here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13960 and here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5402